# Extension to auto-populate wordy pocos?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

Say I have a POCO object that contains a mouthful of properties, i.e.

```cs
class Person
{
  public string Name{get; set;}

  public int ShoeNumber {get; set;}

   // And 19 more properties
}
```

Often, I have a need to assign or copy these values from other objects, i.e. a webrequest containing the same properties.

Is there an extension for VS2019 that will allow me to automatically set up a skeleton piece of code, such that wheen I write:

**var converted = new Person**  (some magic)

And press a magic key combination, it automatically expands to:

```cs
var converted = new Person
{
   Name       = "",
   ShoeNumber = 0,

   // And all the other 19 things
}
```

That would SO help if it exists. If not, I think I may write one.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, but I do agree it would be very useful

Comment: You might want to check out Automapper or a similar library that will do the assignments for you.

Comment: @juharr read the question again, OP is not asking on mapping, but something similar to VS code snippets, but dinamically generated (reading the class properties)

Comment: [Good luck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-displaying-light-bulb-suggestions)

Comment: @bradbury9 The OP stated _I have a need to assign or copy these values from other objects_  the way they seem to want to deal with it is to have their POCO expanded to make it a bit easier to manually map, but I'm suggesting skipping manual mapping altogether.  Also note, it's not an answer, just a suggestion in a comment.

Comment: The answer is gladly accepted @juharr, this is mostly something I use when writing unit-tests and want to prep up some specific values/situations. I use automapper for most of my assignment work, as should everyone :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you want correctly, but it seems to me you might want to take a look at custom snippets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Knoop code snippets will have no access to class code ... it's need custom code analyzer to expand all props to their default values

Comment: @Selvin yeah if they need to be dymanic I misunderstood and snippets won't help.